# Why custom converter should be passed to DeserializeObject instead of using with ItemConverterType?

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

It's not a duplicate as I couldn't find a post explaining why the below happens.

Below is minimal reproducible example that shows `MyTypeJsonConverter` never gets called when used with `ItemConverterType`. But, it does get called when passed to `DeserializeObject`. Why?

**MyTypeJsonConverter does NOT get called**

```
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("type", ItemConverterType = typeof(MyTypeJsonConverter))]
    public MyType MyType { get; set; }
}

static void foo()
{
    var json = "{\"type\":\"data\"}";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json);
}
```

**MyTypeJsonConverter does get called**

```
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public MyType MyType { get; set; }
}

static void foo()
{
    var json = "{\"type\":\"data\"}";
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(json, new MyTypeJsonConverter());
}
```

**MyTypeJsonConverter**

```
public class MyTypeJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyType>
{
    public override MyType ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MyType existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new MyType();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MyType value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would think "item" means something like "list item", doesn't it? Edit: yep, looks like it - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm _"Gets or sets the JsonConverter type used when serializing the **property's collection items.**"_

Comment: [`ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) is for **collection items**.  Use `[JsonConverter(typeof(MyTypeJsonConverter))]`.